# Geoserver cql_filter on wms json/vector requests

Tags: geoserver, cql-filter

I'm trying to make a cql filtered wms request for a non image based format like geojson or mapbox vector but the filters aren't applying. If i change the format to image/png the filters behave as expected.

Is this functionality not supported by geoserver? We're running version 2.11.

Working request (filtered)

```
{{host}}/ows?bbox=16115371.547420282,-4546474.442402283,16115983.043646563,-4545862.946176002&format=image/png&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetMap&srs=EPSG:3857&transparent=true&width=512&height=512&layers=LINE_NB&CQL_FILTER=SEASON_KEY='BASE_2018_SUMMER'
```

Failing request (not filtered)

```
{{host}}/ows?bbox=16115371.547420282,-4546474.442402283,16115983.043646563,-4545862.946176002&format=application/x-protobuf;type=mapbox-vector&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&request=GetMap&srs=EPSG:3857&transparent=true&width=512&height=512&layers=LINE_NB&CQL_FILTER=SEASON_KEY='BASE_2018_SUMMER'
```

URL encoding the query string makes no difference to the result.

Comment: please add which version of GeoServer you are using and example requests that work and fail using the default layers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like this issue has been fixed in a later release. Updating to 2.14 solved this for me. I also did the protobuf 3.6.1 update, not sure if that made a difference at all but the CQL Filters now work.

As a side note, this update also brought with it compatibility for the V2 vector tile spec which is nice, no more Mapbox deprecation warnings.